# Hide the accuracy percentage from the bounding box generated

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Display only the predicted class name and hide the accuracy/confidence percentage from the bounding box made on the detected object

I have trained a custom object detection model and get the bounding boxes with the predicted class name and also the confidence percentage on my object as of now. Below is my code

```
def recognize_object(model_name,ckpt_path,label_path,test_img_path):

    count=0
    sys.path.append("..")

    MODEL_NAME = model_name

    PATH_TO_CKPT = ckpt_path


    PATH_TO_LABELS = label_path

    PATH_TO_IMAGE = list(glob(test_img_path))

    NUM_CLASSES = 3

    label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
    categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
    category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

    detection_graph = tf.Graph()

    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

        sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')


    for paths in range(len(PATH_TO_IMAGE)):
        image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths])
        image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})


        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=4,
        min_score_thresh=0.80)


        coordinates=vis_util.return_coordinates(
        image,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=4,
        min_score_thresh=0.80)

        threshold=0.80


cv2.imwrite("C:\\new_multi_cat\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\frame%d.jpg"%count,image)
        count += 1
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


model_name='inference_graph'
ckpt_path=("C:\\new_multi_cat\\models\\research\\object_detection\\inference_graph\\frozen_inference_graph.pb")
label_path=("C:\\new_multi_cat\\models\\research\\object_detection\\training\\labelmap.pbtxt")
test_img_path=("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\*.jpg")

recognize = recognize_object(model_name,ckpt_path,label_path,test_img_path)
```

suppose my model detectes a tiger from an image. So it makes a bounding box around the detected tiger showing the predicted class name with confidence percentage like (TIGER 80%). I want to display only the predicted class name on my bounding box and not the percentage when the bounding box is made like (TIGER) only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, just add `skip_scores=True` to function `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`. So the function calls is:

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index = category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=4,
    min_score_thresh=0.80,
    skip_scores=True)
```

I've tested on an image from the Kitti dataset. No scores are displayed!
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. I'll try your suggestion on my code as well and will let u know if it works :)